# Feeds: How to import images using Xpath Parser for XML?

Tags: 8, feeds

I am using the Feeds module for XML import. I have created entity type with the Image as a text field. I need to import an image from XML and have it shown on the page.
My XML is like this:

`<Auditor>
      <Ref>RIP.jpg</Ref>
</Auditor>`

I imported the name from XML using Xpath Parser, but I'm unable to display it on the page because of a path that is not mentioned.

How should I set absolute path or display image on the front?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Importing images into a multi-valued image field using image URLs from an XML file is not working for me. The debug output shows the image URLs being parsed correctly, but the images don't get imported.

The XML structure is:

http://www.example.com/files/content/villa-102-1.jpg
          
        
        
          
             http://www.example.com/files/content/villa-102-2.jpg

The context is: //unit
The Xpath query for the image field is: unit_details/images/image/uri

I played around with the image grabber module for feeds, but it failed also.

I was able to import images using the CSV importer and the image URL, so this appears to be a problem with Xpath Parser, not Feeds.